# how to remove namespace and prefix attibutes from a source xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an xml as follows

```
<Publication xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" n1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="InformaKMSStructure.xsd"
```

i want copy all XML but not **xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" and n1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="InformaKMSStructure.xsd"**

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]|@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "@*[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (none provided!):

```
<Publication
 xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 n1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="InformaKMSStructure.xsd">
  <a x="y">
   <b/>
  </a>

  <c/>
</Publication>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Publication>
   <a x="y">
      <b/>
   </a>
   <c/>
</Publication>
```

**Explanation**:

This follows the usual pattern of overriding the identity rule, however the identity rule is replaced by two templates -- one matching any element anf the second matching any other node or attribute.

Comment: Good answer, but the way I read the question, was that he wanted to exclude just the n1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute but not other n1:* attributes as you have done.

Could we not use the stock standard identity transform (instead of your first two templates) with, as Michael has hinted, copy-namespaces="no" on the copy; and in the "black hole" template specify the n1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute instead of wild-carding it?

Comment: As a general rule, when a question puts an XSLT question on SO, but doesn't specify 1.0 or 2.0, what is the proper thing to do? Should we give a 1.0 answer where possible? A 2.0 answer if it is better? Provide both if different? I've been a bit schizophrenic about this.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: This is an XSLT 1.0 solution -- therefore `copy-namespaces="no"` cannot be used. As for which exactly attributes to exclude, it has little meaning to argue about this as the OP hasn't provided a complete XML document -- either of us could have the right or the wrong interpretation as it isn't clear what is right and wrong in this particular case. I have the impression that the OP wants to remove all *visible* namespaces and am solving the problem thus formulated. And thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: I think that if a question is only tagged as "xslt", the OP probably means XSLT 1.0 (and they are generally unaware of the existence of XSLT 2.0) :(

Answer (score 1):

n1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="InformaKMSStructure.xsd" is an ordinary attribute, and the way to "remove" it in XSLT is to refrain from copying it. If you don't do anything in XSLT, you don't produce any output, so if you want to avoid outputting something then you need to find the code that's outputting it and change it. You haven't shown us your code so we can't tell you how to change it.

xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" is different: in the XPath data model it's not treated as an attribute, but as a namespace. In fact, the presence of this namespace declaration causes a namespace node to be present on every element within its scope. To get rid of these namespaces, you need to understand which instructions copy namespaces and which don't. In XSLT 1.0, xsl:copy and xsl:copy-of, when applied to an element, copy all the element's namespaces (whether declared on that element or on an ancestor). To stop this happening, in XSLT 2.0 you can use `<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">`, but in 1.0 the only option is to reconstruct the element using xsl:element rather than xsl:copy.