# remove Name-Space from xml file and save as new XML

Tags: php, xml, namespaces

this is my link to getting XML File:-[XML LINK](http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=13o6&lng=80o12&radius=7000)

this is my code:-

```
<?php
function convertNodeValueChars($node) {
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
      foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
        if ($childNode->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
          $childNode->nodeValue = iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $childNode->nodeValue);
        }
        convertNodeValueChars($childNode);         
      }
    }      
  } 

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=13o6&lng=80o12&radius=7000');
  convertNodeValueChars($doc->documentElement);
  $doc->save('general.xml');  
?>
```

1) i am try to remove ASCII Char to Normal Char
2) want to Remove Name-Space of XML File this is contains name-space`<results xmlns="http://gisgraphy.com">` 
3) want to save as another XML file

Comment: This answer has what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10736557/18771

Comment: @Tomalak no this is not helpfull. i want to remove using php

Comment: There is XSLT support in PHP. It would cost you in the order of 10 lines of code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create on simple php file to load xml From the URL:-

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=22.298569900000000000&lng=70.794301799999970000&radius=7000', true);
$dom->save('filename.xml');
?>
```

then create one XSLT file:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <xsl:template match="*">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and create one php file to load xml file and implement our xslt file:-

```
<?php
$sourcedoc->load('filename.xml');
    $stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
    $stylesheet->load('new4convert.xsl');
     // create a new XSLT processor and load the stylesheet
    $xsltprocessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xsltprocessor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);

    // save the new xml file
    file_put_contents('filename.xml', $xsltprocessor->transformToXML($sourcedoc));
?>
```

final total code if you want to all in one PHP file:-

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=22.298569900000000000&lng=70.794301799999970000&radius=7000', true);
$dom->save('filename.xml');
$sourcedoc = new DOMDocument();
    $sourcedoc->load('filename.xml');
    $stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
    $stylesheet->load('new4convert.xsl');
     // create a new XSLT processor and load the stylesheet
    $xsltprocessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xsltprocessor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);

    // save the new xml file
    file_put_contents('filename.xml', $xsltprocessor->transformToXML($sourcedoc));
?>
```